# Compare getCurrentTime() and time from sharedPref

Tags: java, android

I have tried all the examples on stack. A lot of examples I KNOW. But still did not fix an issue. Cant hadle by myself. 
The main logic is when starts it is checking if sharedPref is null. If not it need to check if current time is already AFTER time which was saved in sharedPref. Here is the code

```
private void makeRandomVisit(final List<User> userList) throws ParseException {
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(mSharedPrefName, MODE_PRIVATE);
    Date date = new Date();
    try {
        date = DateFormat.getDateInstance().parse(prefs.getString(mTriggerTimePrefValue, null));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (prefs.getString(mTriggerTimePrefValue, null) == null || getCurrentTime().after(date)) {
        startVisiting(userList);
        putSharedPrefValue(mTriggerTimePrefValue,getTriggerTime().toString());
    }
}
```

Here is the time from logs

```
            07-02 15:50:00.695 18264-18264/com.example.a3802256.myapplication D/test: currentDate-----> Tue Jul 02 15:50:00 EDT 2019
        07-02 15:50:00.695 18264-18264/com.example.a3802256.myapplication D/test: date-----> Tue Jul 02 15:50:00 EDT 2019
        07-02 15:50:00.695 18264-18264/com.example.a3802256.myapplication D/test: PrefDate-----> Tue Jul 02 16:48:12 EDT 2019
```

I don't know why date is parsing from pref as current date? Was trying to parse it as simpleDate but have an issue with timezone in the middle of the string
Please let me know where might be a problem

Comment: can you print in the log what does `prefs.getString(mTriggerTimePrefValue, null)` returns and share it here?

Comment: The third lane in the logs sample. PrefDate-----> It is correct when you extract it separate as a string. Please share with me ideas if you have